# Invoking button click on ASP.net client side programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I'd like to invoke a button click event on an ASP.net page programmatically, using c#.
I don't have access to the server-side of the page, so i can't invoke the function directly.
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers,
I've used "Tamper Data" add-on for Firefox to see how the generated Post looks like, and built HttpWebRequest of my own.

Answer (score 3):

in your script, call:

`__doPostBack("<%= your_button_id.UniqueID %>", "");`

Comment: worked a treat. if you use `ClientIdMode="Static"` on the control you're trying to simulate a click on, you can just drop the actual ID name in there: `<asp:linkbutton etc etc ClientIdMode="Static" id="myLink">` and in the JS: `__doPostBack("myLink", "");`

Answer (score 1):

As far a s I understand your question:

- you cannot really generate a serverside event call from the client side.
- you can force post back by using a [submit button](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-submit.phtml)
- BUT using

  ```
  javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(...))
  ```

  may fit your need. This is the JS call that an ASP control use. copying that call may "invoke" the method you need

read more here: [WebForm_PostBackOptions documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502060/webformpostbackoptions-documentation)

Enjoy!