# AJAX / ASP.Net / C# : Show next content only after validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, validation

I currently have an ASP.Net `Web Form` that looks like this:
[image]

Each section of this web form is wrapped in its own `div` so that they could be shown or hidden by changing the CSS `display:` property to `none`. My intention is to show each section one at a time, starting with the first one. When the user clicks "Next" the currently visible section will be hidden and the next section will be displayed in its place.

Many of the fields have ASP.Net validation controls attached to them (the "Zip Code" validation error message is displayed in this image as an example).

These validation controls have the `runat=server`

The whole `Web Form` is being loaded into a parent div dynamically through `AJAX`. Each `Next` button is *not* of type `submit` (they are of `<input type= "button">`).

How can I ensure that all fields *in a given section* are validated before allowing the user to hit "Next" ?

I am pretty stuck on this so some assistance would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is each DIV you can have Next button and also you can use one ValidationGroup for button and the controls need to be validated inside div. if you set validation group it will validated only same group controls before post back.

Or you can have one Next button and change validation group of that button by using client side script or code behind when click on next button.

[changing validation group of button with javascript on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042724/changing-validation-group-of-button-with-javascript-on-client-side)

Comment: The problem is that I cannot call `submit` since the page is dynamically placed in a parent div with AJAX.