# WebScraping on dynamicaly called iframes with no src="" on jquery or puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, puppeteer

I have an iframe dynamicaly called by:

`href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(VARİABLES,,true,,false,))`

More exactly, after i click the div mentioned below:

```
<a data-value="XorgstedSOME-VALUElAW0aqrAk=" class="operations-blocks threeText " href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$c$ITEMBoxSelector$ITEMListSelector&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">
        <span id="" class="title">
            item1
        </span>
        <span id="" class="small-text">
            item2
        </span>
        <span id="" class="text">
           USER
        </span>
```

After clicking the div, i am navigated into The iframe with no src, as follows:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" src="" style="visibility: visible;"></iframe>
```

I need to web-scrape this iframe

As I know, javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions() sends a variables into the server, resolves a function there, and then send an URL, which navigates us to the result. [What does webform_DoPostBackWithOptions() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499444/what-does-webform-dopostbackwithoptions-do)
(so that i can't get into js)

Is it possible?

Is it possible to invoke js functions embedded on the given page, via puppeteer if possible.

Is it possible to having a clone of an iframe via invoking js calling it in puppeteer?

Is this related to [UTM parameters](https://nebulaconsulting.co.uk/insights/solving-iframe-blocking/)?

If it is possible to have turn-around with javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(), what are your suggestions?

Comment: Realated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: Can you show how your scraper script looks so far? For me it seems if you do a `page.click('a.threeText')` then you will be able to access the content of the iframe even if the `src` is empty.