# How to convert the href attribute value with WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions into an actual URL?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, dopostback, postbackurl

I have the following anchor tag with this href:

```
<a id="bodyContent_gv_list_lbtn_personname_2" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$bodyContent$gv_list$ctl04$lbtn_personname&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))"><span class="articleText">element</span></a>
```

I need to provide a link directly to the page this href is referncing. I would usually use a selenium driver and use `get_attribute('href')` of an anchor element. However, when I do that I am left with the script as you see writen. When the element is clicked manually the URL in my browser does not change (so I cannot construct it). Is there a way to turn this javascript script into a URL that directly links to the page which it is referncing?

I tried checking if the URL can be manually constructed (but it does not change when the link is clicked).

There is nothing in the useful in XHR or JS in the network tab

Comment: Try following: `href = element.get_attribute("href"); if href.startswith("javascript:"): href=href.split("javascript:", 1)[1]; result = driver.execute_script("return " + href); print(result)` (split by `;`)

Comment: Please provide us url of the site so we can test our code

Comment: It's a post (postback?), so the url is the action of the form but you also need the form vars to make it work

Answer (score 0):

There is no URL. The href is calling a JS method that is updating something. That's why you don't see the page/URL change on click.

Answer (score 0):

***No***, unfortunately you can't translate/construct a direct link to the page this href is referring through the [WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20499444/7429447)

---

### [*PostBackOptions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.postbackoptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1)

> The *PostBackOptions* class allows controls to emit client-side script
> that initiates a postback event. The *PostBackOptions* class also
> provides a reference to the control that initiated the postback event
> through the *TargetControl* property. The postback event is created
> based on the options specified in the *PostBackOptions* object passed
> in to the `ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference` method.

There is no official documentation on the parameters of WebForm_PostBackOptions but the javascript declaration is more or less the same as follows:

```
function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit)
```

Normally, a postback to the server is initiated by elements such as a Submit button or an Image button. However, by emitting client-side JavaScript, different controls can initiate a postback event.