# webscrape website that have this statement: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

Tags: asp.net, r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I'm trying to scrapr [this webpage](https://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/VDTIT/ConsultarVotos.aspx) using `rvest` and `httr` in R.

With the following code I made the table with all documents appear, but I need to download the `pdf` produced for each line of the table.

```
session <- html_session(url)
form <- html_form(session)
form <- form[[1]]
res <- session %>%
  submit_form(form)
```

I understood looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502060/webform-postbackoptions-documentation) that

```
WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ConteudoPagina$gdvEntidade$ctl03$lnkArquivo", "", true, "", "", false, true))
```

Is adding two new parameters to the POST method:

- _EVENTTARGET = 'ctl00$ConteudoPagina$gdvEntidade$ctl03$lnkArquivo'
- _EVENTARGUMENT = ''

So I added this to the form values with:

```
form$fields[["_EVENTTARGET"]] <- list(name = "_EVENTTARGET", value = 'ctl00$ConteudoPagina$gdvEntidade$ctl03$lnkArquivo')
form$fields[["_EVENTARGUMENT"]] <- list(name = "_EVENTARGUMENT", value = '')
```

And re-submitted the form:

```
res2 <- session %>%
  submit_form(form)
```

But `res2` was identical to `res`. How should I submit the form to get the PDF?

Comment: Using `RSelenium`, you can act as a browser and probably get what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, but i would like to avoid using Selenium because it adds a lot of configuration to the project.